# How to reference the deleted layers in Leaflet.draw?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to delete a Leaflet.draw layer from my database in firestore. I can easily delete it from the database side, but i struggle with connecting the document name with the layer name.

More specifically, i can't seem to get the id of the layer to be deleted/edited. Once i have that i should be able to connect it to the document id

This is what i got currently:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.DELETED, e => {
      this.deleteMarkerAnnotation(this.dummyValue)
      console.log(e.propagatedFrom.layers.eachLayer(layer => { console.log(layer) }))
    })
```

I get an error: Cannot read property 'layers' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

propagatedFrom is indeed `undefined`. It is not provided on the event object

just remove `propagatedFrom` and use `e.layers` instead.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.DELETED, e => {
   e.layers.eachLayer(layer => {
      console.log(layer)
   });
})
```

Comment: This worked. And i am now able to reference the deleted item. I had to add ._leaflet_id to layer as well to sort it out. Many thanks

Comment: That's right.  I was gonna write it right now. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) for more info

Comment: I now notice that since i'm retrieving all drawn layers from firestore, they get a new id almost every time i refresh the page. Is there any clever way to keep them at the same id?

Comment: Also another issue is that if i delete several layers, the id also changes

Comment: Since these are new questions , please ask them in new threads